# margin-top and margin-bottom inside floated div not working

Tags: html, css, margin

I have a problem with margin-top and margin-bottom for some elements inside a floated div.

It's a column div floated to the right (I have also 2 other column divs floated to the left)

Demo here:
http://jsfiddle.net/zTb3g/

I need the "float" to adjust columns in the page, but the margin-top and margin-bottom don't work in some of the elements (ex: b, label, a), yet it works normally for other elements (ex: p, input).

I tried a lot of clearing styles in different places of the markup. Hope someone can help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set display:block for the elements. Aside from that, when you have two elements placed one after the other, their margins will overlap. You might consider setting their paddings instead.

Answer (score 0):

See this i think this is what you want http://jsfiddle.net/afshinprofe/zTb3g/1/